# get a value from an async function

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I try to get a value from a function and display it in my TextBox "total1",this is my code:

```
public async void getListePerSearche()
        {
total1.Text = getResultsNumber().Result;
       }
```

and this is the function in which I get the value that I want to send from a rest web service to my TextBox:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> getResultsNumber()
        {
            string numbers;
            try { 
            UriString3 = "MyURL.php";
            var http = new HttpClient();
            http.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
            var response = await http.GetStringAsync(UriString3);//the debugger stops here
            var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NvBarberry.Models.RootObject>(response);
            numbers = rootObject.total;
                return numbers;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.Message.ToString();
            }  
        }
```

the problem is that the debugger stops at this line,and I didn't get any error message or the catch bloc was not even read,

```
 var response1 = await http1.GetStringAsync(UriString3);
```

so,please how can I correct my code,to send the value of variable numbers from the getResultsNumber method to the getListePerSearche method

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use await keyword :

```
public async void getListePerSearche()
{
    total1.Text = await getResultsNumber();
}
```

If you use the property .Result of a Task object, you make a blocking operation. But blocking operations are not allowed on the UI thread.